# Should something be placed between engineered hardwood and a cement slab?

Tags: hardwood

Just installed engineered hardwood floors on the lower level of our home. We have a cement slab. My question is the floors are very very hard.

When installing the floors, should have been a pad placed on cement before installing hardwood?

Comment: Probably yes. Every engineered flooring product should have installation instructions available. If they didn't come in the box, the store or distributor should have them.  Most manufacturers have a website with their documentation available.  What did the instructions say about padding, and especially moisture barriers over concrete?

Comment: There is nothing but vinyl/rubber click lock that tells you no underlayment.  Did you glue your locks together?  If not I would get the wood up as quick as possible.

Comment: …if so, you're kinda screwed. :( Better hope the slab stays bone dry forever!

Answer (score 1):

Yes if it is a floating floor. If it is a glue down floor, no it is not possible. Grunthos is correct on the availability of instructions. They are always available.